# Selecting to XML from SQL - Drop/Exclude NULL and 0 (zero) values from results

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Generating XML from SQL server, however I want to exclude items from results that are NULL or 0 (zero). Is this possible? I've attached a sample of the SELECT statement along with some XML results.

```
SELECT 
VehicleID AS 'VehicleID/@id',
SubModelID AS 'SubModelID/@id',
EngineID AS 'EngineID/@id',
FROM myTable
FOR XML PATH('App')
```

Here is a sample result:

```
<App>
   <VehicleID id="128001" />
   <SubModelID id="295" />
   <EngineID id="0" />
</App>
```

I'd like to exclude the EngineID result (or any others) in the case where the ID=0, like the following:

```
<App>
   <VehicleID id="128001" />
   <SubModelID id="295" />
</App>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL values will not add a value to your XML.

To exlude 0 from the result you can use `nullif(columnname,  0)`.

Comment: Perfect! Was unaware of the NULLIF() function.